# Getting the color of the text using iText

Tags: java, itext, itext7

My current project involves extracting meaningful information from PDF documents. To achieve the final objective, I have been trying to extract the forecolor of the text. I present a snapshot from one of the documents.
[image: Snapshot from PDF]

The color of the encircled text comes out as **Black**. I suspect that I am going wrong somewhere, however I do get accurate text color information from some of the documents.

I have pasted the relevant lines of code from the **LocationExtractionStrategy** derivation:

```
public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
        iTextSharp.text.BaseColor colorStroke=renderInfo.GetStrokeColor();
        iTextSharp.text.BaseColor colorFill = renderInfo.GetFillColor();
        Color rgbFill=ConvertToRGB(colorFill);
        Color rgbStroke=ConvertToRGB(colorStroke);
        //rgbFill and rgbStroke turn[![enter image description here][2]][2] out to be black. Why?
}

private System.Drawing.Color ConvertToRGB(BaseColor colorIText)
{
    if (colorIText == null) return System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    var col = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(colorIText.R, colorIText.G, colorIText.B);
    return col;
}
```

Comment: From the `iTextSharp.text.BaseColor` I infer you are using `iTextSharp`, which is not `iText7`. I am removing `itext7` tag from this question.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: As you can see, I am using the methods *GetStrokeColor* and *GetFillColor* , both of which return me objects of type *iTextSharp.text.BaseColor* . The R,G,B components give me the color *Black* for the encircled text. I was expecting some other color. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to share the PDF because these are highly client confidential.

Comment: There are multiple ways the visible colour of text may be different from the filling colour active at the text drawing command. Without the PDF I cannot tell which is used in  your case. That been said... you retrieve the `R`, `G`, and `B` components. Are you sure the colour is a RGB colour?

Comment: In this specific case, the R,G,B components are all 0. How would I determine from an instance of *iTextSharp.text.BaseColor* whether the colour is a RGB colour?  Thanks.